# Why does my sink disposal come loose from the locking ring?

Tags: plumbing, kitchen-sink

I am having a hard time installing a new insinkerator in a new sink.

I followed all the steps in installation manual and set the flange. When I try to mount the motor to the flange, it basically wont set firmly. The locking ring does engage and rides up the ramps but the unit is loose and falls. It’s almost as if some part is missing.

I’m not even sure how is this supposed to work. The mounting ring diameter is larger than the black plastic neck of the garbage disposal. It slides right out as shown on last photo. So how is it supposed to hold it in place? On the old unit (last photo), the mounting ring is already on the unit and won’t slide out as the neck is thicker. On new unit, the mounting ring slides on and off the neck freely.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you install the split ring that holds the mounting piece to the disposer?

Comment: also when you mount it put the disposer on a bottle jack to raise it to the sink attachment area and than finagle it to the lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easier if you have two people but if not, you need to position the disposal in place and then work the locking ring into place making sure all three "ramps" are engaged and turn it clockwise to tighten. The last step is to take the angled allen wrench and put it into one of the round sleeves on the collar and push hard to lock the ring in place. You might have to move the wrench around the ring using all the sleeves to balance the locking force.

Comment: the problem is, I can’t even get to that last step. The rong does seemingly engage, it’s just the disposal won’t stay in place

Comment: There should be a rubber bushing/cap that goes over the disposal top after the ring is in place over the top of the disposal. See if the bushing/cap is stuck in the sink drain piece or maybe stuck inside the disposal.

Comment: On the ring that is on the disposal there are 3 tabs that curl IN, they must line up to 3 corresponding slots on the basket. Then you have push up hard on the bottom of the disposal while turning the ring so the tabs move onto and up into the ring on the basket. You can see a demonstration At the 6:40 time mark on the following video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BlbSBXfpgxg

Comment: I think what may have happened is I may have left that part on the old sink I gave to a friend. Hoping she still has it :)

Comment: The rubber collar, or bushing, lives on the disposal. If the bushing was not on there then it would be fairly easy to get the two rings to screw together and then the disposal would just be sloppy and loose.   If you need the bushing  You can buy the rubber bushing separately in the Plumbing Supply section of your local home improvement Center. https://www.lowes.com/pd/InSinkErator-3-in-Rubber-Garbage-Disposal-Splash-Guard/3065643

Comment: @David There should be a new ring. Did you look in the drain piece you installed in the sink or inside the new disposal?

Comment: So as it turns out, I let the rubber bussing go with the old sink when I gave away the cabinets. The friend who got it was kind enough to take it off for me and all is good. I am marking this as an answer because provided all parts are present, this is the way to install the garbage disposal.